# angular flex layout responsive form

Tags: css, angular, responsive-design

we're using this lib : https://github.com/angular/flex-layout

so far, we have below code to achive the fxlayout, but it did not work in mobile device.

```
<div fxLayout="column" id="width">
     <div class="table-cell" fxLayout="row">
            <div fxLayout="column" class="columnlabel">
              <label class="f_label margintop">width </label>
            </div>
            <div fxLayout="column leftpadding">
              <input type="number" matInput 
                 style="font-weight: bold;background: white;margin-top: 2px;" name="width">
                </div>
              </div>
        </div>
```

what i am looking for is,

when it is mobile device want input control as underneath to label

when it is large device want textbox on right side

but in some case want input control on right side in mobile also, for example, tongle switch control.

please click on below link for sample representation, and can you please guide me what i am missing ?
[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m66js.png)

provided sample work on stack blitz as requested in comment. Thanks

https://flex-layout-angular-material-wqeqvc.stackblitz.io/

https://stackblitz.com/edit/flex-layout-angular-material-wqeqvc?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: hi, you should add more code or make a snippet in order to help you

Comment: @Vova - sure, i will try to make a stackblitz

Comment: @Vova - updated the question with snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to achieve is probably something like that with their [responsive API](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Responsive-API):

```
<div fxLayout="column" fxLayout.gt-xs="row">
    <label class="f_label margintop">Sports </label>
    <input type="number" matInput>
</div>
<div fxLayout="column" fxLayout.gt-xs="row">
        <label class="f_label margintop">Country </label>
        <input type="number" matInput>
</div>
```

By default with *fxLayout*, it will be in ROW and when the screen is bigger than xs, then it's in column with *fxLayout.gt-xs*

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/flex-layout-angular-material-wqeqvc?file=app/app.component.html